# Vagrant Push configure src directory on guest machine

Tags: vagrant

```
config.push.define "ftp" do |push|

        # Login Credentials
        push.host = "104.131.46.134"
        push.username = "root"
        push.password = "password"

        # FTP vs SFTP
        push.secure = "true"

        # Where to copy the files on the server
        push.destination = "/var/www/html"

        # Where are App is
        push.dir = "public"
    end
```

I have above code above. I understand   push.destination = "/var/www/html"   points to actually directory on the remote server. How do you specify source directory on guest machine? My Wordpress Theme is hosted on `/usr/usrname/public_html/wp_content.`

Should I put

```
push.dir = "/usr/usrname/public_html/wp_content"
```

and it would work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, per [doc](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/push/ftp.html#dir)

> `dir` - The base directory containing the files to upload. By default this is the same directory as the Vagrantfile, but you can specify this if you have a `src` folder or `bin` folder or some other folder you want to upload.

so if the host files that you want to push are on `/usr/usrname/public_html/wp_content` you will have

```
push.dir = "/usr/usrname/public_html/wp_content"
```

Comment: Nice, let me give this a try and select your answer!

Comment: Thanks, it answered my question but I still have an issue with pointing to correct directory on host machine

Comment: where are the files on your host ? you can indicate absolute path (starting with `/` or relative path to your current Vagrantfile)